# What is this form element called and how to do it

Tags: javascript, html

[alt text http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/5020/whatbox.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/5020/whatbox.png)

I dont know what this is called, but you have 2 lists, and a button(s) in the middle to switch options back and forth.

Question [a] What is this called.

Question [b] How do you make one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some call it a DualListBox and here is some jquery to get it to work...this example actually has buttons to move items back and forth between the listboxes.

### **JQUERY**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btnright").click(function() { $('select[name=ListBox1] option:selected').appendTo('.ListBox2'); });
    $(".btnleft").click(function() { $('select[name=ListBox2] option:selected').appendTo('.ListBox1'); });
});
```

---

**ASP code (but can just use html buttons and select boxes)**

```
  <div>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" CssClass="ListBox1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" CssClass="ListBox2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
        <br />
        <span class='btnleft'><<< Left </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class='btnright'>Right
            >>> </span>
```

Comment: What's with the ASP.NET stuff? How is that relevant?

Comment: if you have trouble converting it....you have more issues....

Comment: It is just an example....thought was pretty simple to convert if you know HTML..

Comment: The ASP.NET stuff isn't relevant. His answer is a good one though, regardless. @CSharpAtl: It would make more sense to do the above code in HTML instead of ASP since the requester didn't mention anything about ASP.

Comment: @KyleFarris - agreed it is not relevant, but it is my paradigm and was the quickest way to throw together an example...

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [jquery crossSelect plugin](http://wheresrhys.co.uk/resources/crossSelect/crossSelect.html) to do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 3):

It's called `<select>`

```
<select name="myName" size="5">
    <option value="v1">val1</option>
    <option value="v2">val2</option>
    <option value="v3">val3</option>
</select>
```

As for moving the items between two controls you need to remove one option from the first select box and append it to the second one. This must be done by JavaScript.

Comment: Well, one part of it is.

Answer (score 1):

You would have two <select>'s with a button in the middle.  on button click you would use javascript to move the selected ones to the second <select>